# This code keeps giving me errors and I don't see it where is could be

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE TRACKING_RECORD(
    ReaderID int(11) NOT NULL,
    EPC int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
    Latitude varchar(30),
    Longitude varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (ReaderID,EPC,`Timestamp`)
    on UPDATE CASCADE );
```

The error is at "ON UPDATE CASCADE"
and it asks for a closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` is part of *foreign key* syntax, not *primary key* syntax.  In this context, it makes no sense, so just remove it:

```
CREATE TABLE TRACKING_RECORD (
    ReaderID int(11) NOT NULL,
    EPC int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
    Latitude varchar(30),
    Longitude varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (ReaderID, EPC, `Timestamp`)
);
```

I would advise you to avoid composite primary keys.  Instead, have a single auto-incremented primary key and define the other as `unique`:

```
CREATE TABLE TRACKING_RECORD (
    TrackingRecordId int auto_increment primary key,
    ReaderID int(11) NOT NULL,
    EPC int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
    Latitude varchar(30),
    Longitude varchar(30),
    UNIQUE (ReaderID, EPC, `Timestamp`)
);
```

Comment: oh ok, but the column in this table reference 3 other table except for timestamp.  Timestamp is a partial key, would it be the same as making it unique? sorry for late reply 1am where im at

Comment: @abdul_moham101 . . . You have no foreign key references in your question.  Nor do you have any other tables.  If you have a more complex question, I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Changing this question can invalidate answers, which can draw downvotes.

Comment: Alright now its making sense. I didnt think about the foreign keys. Ill try to put the foreign keys in and see if it works out